# Seeking soil depth data for Washington State?

Tags: soils

I need to make a map of Whitman County showing different classes of soil depth available in Whitman County.

I have been searching this data in SSURGO and the Web Soil Survey Database. The only thing close to this that I can find is "Depth to any restrictive layer", but I cannot find the actual soil depth data anywhere I look.

If "Depth to the restrictive layer" and "Soil depth" are not the same thing, where can I find soil depth data?

Comment: The SSURGO metadata should help you make that distinction.

Comment: @StuSmith I got the result i needed by contacting the person in NRCS itself. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

NRCS has their web Soil Survey and

This is what you need is to go here : https://websoilsurvey.nrcs.usda.gov/app/

You will need to find the depth there in the database and you would need to run to make it both joining the table with the layer and the database.

Yes it's going to be not easy but you should be able to do it..

If you are stuck, best way is to contact their NRCS your state and speak to their State Soil Scientist and he or she will guide you there...

Comment: that is exactly what i did. The person i contacted with was helpful

Comment: @Samrat If this answer helped you then you should consider upvoting and accepting it.